# Does information on the multiset of $m$-subsequences fully determine a word of length $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

For example, take the word "EGG" of length 3.

The 1-subsequences (subsequences of length 1) are: E, G, G

However, knowledge of the 1-subsequences does not fully determine the word, since another word "GGE" has the same (multi)set of 1-subsequences.

The 2-subsequences of "EGG" (counting multiplicity) are: EG, EG, GG

This seems to fully determine the word, since no other word of length 3 has the same (multi)set of 2-subsequences.

Is there such a result:

Conjecture: "The multiset $S$ of $m$-subsequences either fully determine a word of length $n$, or no such word of length $n$ exists that corresponds to $S$". (Where $m$ is a fixed integer between 2 and $n$)

Or rephrased in another way: "Is it possible for two distinct words of length $n$ to have the same multiset of -subsequences?"

Is there any elementary way to prove it / generate counterexamples?

Thanks for any help.

---

Update: bof has provided a counterexample for $m=2$.
ABBA and BAAB both have the same multiset of 2-subsequences: AB, AB, AA, BB, BA, BA.

The conjecture is clearly true for $m=n$ (a word of length $n$ has only one unique subsequence of length $n$, namely itself).

Are there any other values of $m$ where the conjecture can be proven to be true or false?

Comment: @bof I have edited the conjecture to be more clear. (Either fully determine a word, or no such word exists). Or in other words, I am just interested to know if two distinct words can have the same multiset of $m$-subsequences.

Comment: @bof You are right! That is indeed a counter-example to the "conjecture".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m=2$ the words ABBA and BAAB give a counterexample.

In fact, for any fixed $m$, the conjecture will fail for sufficiently large $n$. Namely, considering a binary alphabet, the number of possible words of length $n$ is $2^n$, while the number of possible multisets of $m$-subsequences of such a word is no greater than $\binom{\binom nm+2^m-1}{2^m-1}$, so it suffices to take $n$ so that
$$2^n\gt\binom{\binom nm+2^m-1}{2^m-1}.$$

**P.S.** A word of length $n$ has $\binom nm$ $m$-subsequences, each of which is one of the $2^m$ words of length $m$. The right side of the inequality is the "stars-and-bars" expression for the number of solutions of $$x_1+\cdots+x_{2^m}=\binom nm$$ in nonnegative integers. Of course, for the existence proof, we could use a much cruder bound, as long as it's polynomial in $n$.

**P.P.S.** On the other hand, for $m=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}2\right\rceil$ the conjecture is true.

First, it suffices to consider a $2$-letter alphabet; if for each pair of distinct letters we can determine the subsequence formed by the occurrences of those two letters, then we can determine the word.

Suppose we have a word of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{\text{A,B}\}$, and we know its multiset of $m$-subsequences. It follows that, for each $k\le m$, we also know its multiset of $k$-subsequences. In particular we know the number of A's and B's in the word, say $a$ A's and $b$ B's. Since $a+b=n\lt2m$, we have $\min(a,b)\lt m$. Without loss of generality we assume $a\lt m$.

Since $a+1\le m$, we know the multiset of $(a+1)$-subsequences, in particular, the ones consisting of $a$ A's and one B. Now the number of $(a+1)$-subsequences BAA...A is the number of B's before the first A; the number of subsequences ABA...A is the number of B's between the first and second A; and so on.

**P.P.P.S.** There seems to be no counterexample for $m=3$ and $n=6$, but ABBBAAB and BAABBBA give a counterexample for $m=3$ and $n=7$. (Done by hand, though this is the sort of thing that lends itself to automation.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain briefly how you got the binomial coefficient?